# Get Specific text from powershell invoke

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get a specific part of text out from an `Invoke-WebRequest` using powershell.

The following code:

```
$w = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri  "url"

$w.AllElements | where class -EQ "centerControl" | select innerText
```

Outputs the following:

```
innerText                                                                                                                            
---------                                                                                                                            
.FooterLinkCovid { font-size: 16px; color: #B6975F; } a.FooterLinkCovid:hover, a.FooterLinkCovid:active { text-decoration: underli...
Copyright © 2021  | Terms & Conditions | Security | Contact Us |  Proudly developed in South Africa. | 5.0.2038.0 ()
```

So i tried the following to get specific text:

```
$w = $w.toString() -split "[`r`n]" | select-string "5"
```

What I am trying to achieve is basically getting the version number which `5.0.2038.0` from the inner text but I cant seem to get it right

Comment: You need to show us the actual part of the html in full of this element with classname `centerControl`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works from your sample text:

```
$w = ".FooterLinkCovid { font-size: 16px; color: #B6975F; } a.FooterLinkCovid:hover, a.FooterLinkCovid:active { text-decoration: underli...
Copyright © 2021  | Terms & Conditions | Security | Contact Us |  Proudly developed in South Africa. | 5.0.2038.0 ()  "

$version = $w.Trim().Split(" ")[-2]
# 5.0.2038.0
```

You might have to massage it a bit to work with the actual web page though to get the right value for `$w` out of it to start with.

Answer (score 0):

The --> `n`  is for New line and the `r` is for Carriage return. Here the output has 2 lines so if you do `split "[rn]"` you get nothing relevant. Instead use `split(" ")` or `split("|")`. So then you will get a list of elements cut with this pattern.
For instance, if you do `$w.split(" ")`, with `$w` being the innertext:

```
.FooterLinkCovid { font-size: 16px; color: #B6975F; } a.FooterLinkCovid:hover, a.FooterLinkCovid:active { text-decoration: underli...
Copyright © 2021  | Terms & Conditions | Security | Contact Us |  Proudly developed in South Africa. | 5.0.2038.0 ()
```

You will get

```
.FooterLinkCovid
{
font-size:
16px;
color:
#B6975F;
}
a.FooterLinkCovid:hover,
a.FooterLinkCovid:active
{
text-decoration:
underli...
Copyright
©
2021

|
Terms
&
Conditions
|
Security
|
Contact
Us
|

Proudly
developed
in
South
Africa.
|
5.0.2038.0
()
```

Then you can grab your version with a pattern for instance. \d is for a decimal number and . is a dot which has been escaped.
So this would be

```
$w.split(" ") | Select-String -Pattern "\d\.\d\.\d\d\d\d\.\d"
```

to grab the exact "5.0.2038.0" pattern

or if you just want to grab the 5.0 pattern, do it with

```
$w.split(" ") | Select-String -Pattern "\d\.\d\."
```

PS: It seems that you are trying to escape characters a bit like in java, and you are probably on windows 7. There the commands are not exactly the same based on the Os you have (Windows 7 has older powershell versions with less options. Windows 10 has ps v.5). I do it with windows 10 v.2004.